# Help with checking for flashVars value in embed code AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, if-statement, try-catch

hoping for a bit of direction and help with a frustrating issue right now.

Originally I thought it was a problem with my Try / Catch statement, but in reality my issue is really just trying to do a check in an If / Else statement to see if my Flash player can obtain any data from a flashVar. If flashVar VID = great, Else read from an XML file.

**Basically this is what I need to have happen:**

- Check to see if there are flashVar values
- If so then load the other Class files and DO NOT get the XML file
- If not then run the code in the Catch statement and load the XML file

**UPDATED CODE** I put a lot of comments to explain what I'm trying to do :(

```
public function playerLive():void
{
// Attempt to load from HTML EMBED
// Maybe the problem is here? 
// Tried different syntax / keywords no luck so far

//if (this.loaderInfo.parameters["VID"])
//if (stage.loaderInfo.parameters["file"])
//if (this.loaderInfo.parameters.hasOwnProperty("file"))
if(root.loaderInfo.parameters.hasOwnProperty("VID") && root.loaderInfo.parameters.VID != null)
{
    // Trying keyword root
    varVid   = root.loaderInfo.parameters.VID;
    varChid  = root.loaderInfo.parameters.CHID;
    vidURL   = root.loaderInfo.parameters.file;
    vidSplit = vidURL.split(".flv")[0].split("/");
    vidTitle = root.loaderInfo.parameters.title;
    vidKey   = root.loaderInfo.parameters.keyURL;

    // - Trying keyword stage
    /*varVid   = stage.loaderInfo.parameters.VID;
    varChid  = stage.loaderInfo.parameters.CHID;
    vidURL   = stage.loaderInfo.parameters.file;
    vidSplit = vidURL.split(".flv")[0].split("/");
    vidTitle = stage.loaderInfo.parameters.title;
    vidKey   = stage.loaderInfo.parameters.keyURL;*/

    // - Trying keyword this
    /*varVid   = this.loaderInfo.parameters.VID;
    varChid  = this.loaderInfo.parameters.CHID;
    vidURL   = this.loaderInfo.parameters.file;
    vidSplit = vidURL.split(".flv")[0].split("/");
    vidTitle = this.loaderInfo.parameters.title;
    vidKey   = this.loaderInfo.parameters.keyURL;*/

    setup();

} else {

    varVid  = urlVars.VID
    varChid = urlVars.CHID
    xmlURL = "http://www.howdini.com/H_player_xml.php?VID="+varVid+"&CHID="+varChid;
    readXML();
}

// The old code
/*try {
    varVid   = this.loaderInfo.parameters.VID;
    varChid  = this.loaderInfo.parameters.CHID;
    vidURL   = this.loaderInfo.parameters.file;
    vidSplit = vidURL.split(".flv")[0].split("/");
    vidTitle = this.loaderInfo.parameters.title;
    vidKey   = this.loaderInfo.parameters.keyURL;
    setup();

// Facebook Player
    } catch (e) {
    varVid  = urlVars.VID
    varChid = urlVars.CHID
    xmlURL  = "http://www.howdini.com/H_player_xml.php?VID="+varVid+"&CHID="+varChid;
    readXML();
    }
}*/
}

function readXML():void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoadSuccess);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onXmlLoadFailed);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(xmlURL));
}

function onXmlLoadFailed(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    //xml failed to load;
}

function onXmlLoadSuccess(event:Event):void
{
    //parse your xml, then run setup;
    setup();
}
```

What the embed code looks like (some values renamed for security reasons):

```
<object width=450 height=292 border=0 >
<embed src="http://dev.mysite.com/flvplayer_lite.swf" width="450" height="292" 
flashvars="file=http://limelightserver.net/o18/VideoName.flv&VID=13&CHID=6&title=Video Title&keyURL=118258&autostart=false&showfsbutton=false&c1=1&c2=8430754&c3=8430754&c4=Category Namec5=02" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" border="0" wmode="transparent">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Have you investigated the exception that is being caught? I am assuming it is a NullReference but..

Comment: I'm not sure what the exception would be? I guess NullReference sounds right, but not sure what to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and catch is to catch errors, not a simple conditional.

All you need is:

```
if(stage.loaderInfo.parameters["VID"])
{
  ... load the embed version
}else{
   ... load the xml version
}
```

Comment: thanks, trying that, but now neither the URL version or the Embed version works. Should Stage be this? What is the difference?

Comment: @ Leon - try the following: `if(loaderInfo.parameters.VID)/*...*/`

Comment: That worked! Thx www0z0k :) And bjornson, and everyone else that suggested originally changing my Try/Catch into an if/else

Answer (score 2):

Can you not try something like this...

```
    function init():void
    {
        // check to see if loaderInfo params are available
        // if they are initalise vars and run setup()
        // else load xml, parse it, and then call setup()

        if(root.loaderInfo.parameters.hasOwnProperty("VID") && root.loaderInfo.parameters.VID != null)
        {
            varVid = root.loaderInfo.parameters.VID;

            varChid = root.loaderInfo.parameters.CHID;
            vidURL = root.loaderInfo.parameters.file;
            vidSplit = vidURL.split(".flv")[0].split("/");
            vidTitle = root.loaderInfo.parameters.title;
            vidKey = root.loaderInfo.parameters.keyURL;

            // comScore
            c1 = root.loaderInfo.parameters.c1;
            c2 = root.loaderInfo.parameters.c2;
            c3 = root.loaderInfo.parameters.c3;
            c4 = root.loaderInfo.parameters.c4;
            c5 = root.loaderInfo.parameters.c5;

            setup();
        }
        else
        {
            // variables in URL not FlashVars: http://mysite.com/player.swf?VID=13&CHID=2
            varVid = urlVars.VID
            varChid = urlVars.CHID

            xmlURL = "http://www.mysite.com/player_xml.php?VID=" + varVid + "&CHID=" + varChid;
            readXML();
        }
    }

    function readXML():void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoadSuccess);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onXmlLoadFailed);
        loader.load(new URLRequest(xmlURL));
    }

    function onXmlLoadFailed(event:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        //xml failed to load;
    }

    function onXmlLoadSuccess(event:Event):void
    {
        //parse your xml, then run setup;
        setup();
    }

    function setup():void
    {
        drawVideo();
        drawSplash();
        drawControls();
        drawBorder();
        vd.playerCntrls = pc;
        pc.videoDsply = vd;
        pc.scrnButton = sp;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying that still didn't work, I'm going to update my question because it's not about Try/Catch it is how to check if there are certain flashvars on the page.